# Why does google does not ignore the word "languages", although I have set to ignore it in advanced search settings

Tags: google, google-search

Why does google does not ignore the word "languages", although I have set to ignore it in advanced search settings.

here is the term I am using in google search:

-languages site:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/

and here is the first result where the word "languages" is still present, (you can do a quick crtl+F to find out)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Bedell_Smith

I am just curious to know why google have not ignored the word "languages"?

Comment: You realize that term appears on *a lot* of pages on Wikipedia, right? It's in the standard sidebar if something's been translated. (It's also not shown on talk, history, etc.) Ignoring your–possibly questionable–filter, what are you actually trying to do here? You might just be going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered that maybe it *is* being filtered?
The instance of "languages" you're complaining about is in the (near-)sitewide sidebar. There's a decent chance Google is ignoring that entire area for indexing/results purposes. I've checked a random assortment of ~20 results for that search, and while yes the word always appears there, it has so far *never* appeared in the actual article content, only in the navigation.

Obviously this isn't definitive until you check a much larger number of the results, but it's suggestive.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, however, I am unable to understand your answer totally. Please reply.

Comment: "There's a decent chance Google is ignoring that entire area for indexing/results purposes." So you mean google index only some portion of a website?

Comment: @all                  anyone answering my question?

Comment: They likely store everything for a page, but there are methods for determining what's likely the actual content in a page. So, even though the word you're trying to filter out appears in the document, note that it doesn't seem to appear in the content. And you still haven't answered: what are you actually trying to do with that search?